# Where are assemblies in .NET physically located?

Tags: .net, assemblies, file-structure

I am a little confused about where .NET assemblies are physically located. Take good old [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). In my `web.config` file it says:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

This is the reference to LINQ. But where exactly is the DLL this refers to located? There isn't any path in the above and it's not in my bin folder.

I also have what I think is a third-party assembly reference:

```
<add assembly="MapInfo.CoreTypes, Version=4.0.0.483, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=F548BCBA69D4B8DA" />
```

How can I tell where this is located on my machine if it's not in the `bin` folder?

Also, if a DLL file is in the `bin` directory, can I assume that it doesn't need to be referenced in `web.config`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Third-party assemblies might not be in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), see MSDN article *[How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)* for the set of rules. Or, try the SysInternals [FILEMON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor#FileMon).

Answer (score 15):

I think they are located in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), which is located in `%WINDIR%\Assembly`. More information is in *[Demystifying the .NET Global Assembly Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4352/Demystifying-the-NET-Global-Assembly-Cache)* (at [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)).

Comment: Yours is likely at URL
 `file:///C:/Windows/Assembly/GAC/` (wish I could force that to be a link)

Comment: What about MapInfo.CoreTypes, if that is third party where would it be located?

Comment: if it's been registered with the gac, it's probably located there.  is it not there?

Comment: @Petra.  They *might* be gac'd.  They might simply be whereever you installed them.  Personally, I wish the GAC didn't exist and instead forced the apps to have their own BIN directories.

Comment: unless it's being added as a reference just using the dll, as in the example here http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/TechSupp/MIProd.nsf/8248bf2b72f6949585257125006b035a/220c3abad4cd681785256f890054e4fc?OpenDocument , in which case it's located under the program files somewhere.

Comment: These reasons are precisely why you need use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (see my answer).

Answer (score 6):

Some of the .Net Assemblies are located in the installation folder of .Net

Such as

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

Inside there are the assemblies sitting. In the .NETFramework one level up you would find the different versions of .NET and their corresponding assemblies.

Comment: No. These are the reference assemblies. They are skeleton assemblies, without actual implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Assembly and Fusion path probing is pretty complicated. I will say that typically .NET will resolve an assembly from one of two places:

1. Either it will find it in local directory, like the current directory, a bin subdirectory, or other place specified by the Fusion assembly-binding logic, or
2. it will find it in the global GAC store, where assemblies can be registered and looked up by name, version, and a couple other attributes.

To address your specific question about the 'bin' directory, if you're using ASP.NET (which I assume from your reference to `web.config`), then yes, you don't need to include the path - ASP.NET will take care of whatever it needs to do in order to make .NET look for assemblies in the 'bin' directory.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: it depends on alot of things.  The framework has its [rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) for how it loads assemblies.  However, you can override this using the various config files (machine.config, etc).  To find out where your assemblies actually live on a particular system, use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).  (It's part of the platform SDK.  Just open up an SDK command shell and run fuslogvw.exe.)

Answer (score 3):

An assembly can be found mostly in either of the following places:

- [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) - C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC (Microsoft
  provided and by third-party in some
  cases)
- Installation folder (most of the
  third-party controls)

You can get path and other information about an assembly by right clicking on the assembly in your project references and selecting *Properties*.